# Flash Builder, Air - NativeProcess API error

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder

In all samples for how to use Native Process API i can see the following line:

**process = new NativeProcess();**

when i try to run the sample i get an error:

Description Resource Path Location Type
1120: **Access of undefined property process**. testProj.mxml /testProj/src line 61 Flex Problem

what should i do? this process is not declared anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the right way to define a var in flash as a NativeProcess type

var process:NativeProcess;